# Can I automatically delete meetings from Outlook calendar if a user takes no action?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation, calendar

I'm trying to ease the overuse of our meeting room.

I want to automatically delete meetings in our Outlook calendar if the system does not receive confirmation from the user when the meeting starts. My plan is to put an iPad in each room. The user can use this iPad to input their ID for confirmation.

Is this possible?... (SharePoint, Aspx or anything to achieve this)

Comment: Or can I login meeting room's outlook account on iPad, user use outlook client to input their ID.

Comment: What happens in the case that the meeting organiser is a late?

Comment: All interns and administrative assistants in company like to book room for their line manager in advance, but when the meeting is canceled or postponed, they won't take any actions...